# Refresh fuelux treeview on fileupload

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, treeview, fuelux

I'm using jquery fileupload plugin to upload a file and then populating the data from a file to fuelux treeview. I have put an ajax call for processing the file data where the data is received and then the tree is populated. For the first time when I visit the page and upload the file, the treeview populates the data fine, but the problem appears when I delete the file and reupload another/same file to extract the data from. The file gets uploaded successfully and treeDataSrouce also contains the data in appropriate required format but the $('#tree').ace_tree() function inside the ajax success call doesn't repopulate the tree. I few things and also checked the related answers on forum but none of them helped. Please any help will be highly appreciated.

Bilal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the same set of kit as you: AceAdmin template, JQuery fileupload, and FuelUx treeview.

Ace has put a wrapper around FuelUX treeview, but you can reach it directly through .tree().

I used the following delegated event to listen for the fileuploaddone from jquery fileupload and call tree('reload') to re-pull from my dynamic datasource:

```
$('body').on('fileuploaddone', function() {
  $('.filebrowser').tree('reload');
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry for getting back after a long long time (just been trying different things including the above you suggested) but the tree reloading didn't work for me as I was reloading the data via knockout.js without refreshing. I resolved the problem by completely removing fuelux tree with a css based tree which worked perfectly for me. Thanks for your valued comment above